# debezium sqlserver cdc connect to kafka, but can get data

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, debezium

The log of kafka connect just like below:

> Either no records were produced by the task since the last offset commit, or every record has been filtered out by a transformation or dropped due to transformation or conversion errors.

and this is my config:

worker.properties

```
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
rest.port=9093
rest.host.name=localhost
rest.advertised.port=9093
rest.advertised.host.name=localhost
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
plugin.path=/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins
```

connector.properties

```
name=sql-server-connection
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector
database.hostname=localhost
database.port=1433
database.user=sa
database.password=LiuLei123qwe
database.dbname=testDB
database.server.name=server1
table.whitelist=dbo.inventory
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=sqlserver.inventory
```

Comment: What is unclear about the log? Sounds like the table has no data to read

Comment: the sqlserver cdc table do have data, like this:    __$start_lsn __$end_lsn __$seqval __$operation __$update_mask id name cost __$command_id
0x00000049000066500003 NULL 0x00000049000066500002 2 0x07 5 coin 100.00 1

Comment: what version you are on? mine is table.include.list instead of table.whitelist